# How can I perform a non-blocking check for closure of a multiprocessing Pipe in linux?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've read [the python docs on multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and I've written several programs.

I've scoured Google and Stack Overflow, but to no avail.

On Linux, I simply want to check if a pipe has been closed on the other end **and its likely that the pipe will contain no data to be `recv()`'d** ... my code has other processing to do - so I don't want it blocking while I wait for the closure!

The simplest possible example I've been tinkering with is below, I've also investigated Windows.  I'm sure this behavior wont be surprising.

On **Windows**:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing import Pipe
>>> p,c=Pipe()
>>> c.close()
>>> p.poll()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 257,
in poll
    return self._poll(timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 328,
in _poll
    _winapi.PeekNamedPipe(self._handle)[0] != 0):
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 109] The pipe has been ended
```

*That's great!* I could simply catch the `BrokenPipeError` exception.

On **Linux**:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing import Pipe
>>> p,c=Pipe()
>>> c.close()
>>> p.poll()
True
>>>
```

*That's not so great!* Is there is a better way than to call `recv()` and have my code block?

Yes, I could send an 'END' string from the other side, but that seems mechanically inelegant.

Feels like I'm missing an option ...

Comment: What prevents you from using `c.closed`?

Comment: The documentation! I can't find any mention of it in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Connection but also I want to check if the connection has been closed from the other end (from p, not c).

Comment: Look at `help(Connection)`. But now I am worried that this undocumented property might not be part of the intended API. Also, `Pipe()` returns instances of the undocumented class `PipeConnection` which is a sibling, not a descendant of `Connection`. I don't think they are going anywhere but you might want to look for more qualified advice, maybe in the python users mailing list.

Comment: If you want to know wether the pipe was closed by `c` you need to check `c.closed`. That is why I asked, you should be able to orchestrate your code so yo have a reference to `c` where you need it but if this is a problem you should edit the question and explain why.

Comment: For me, `help('multiprocessing.connection')`, `help('multiprocessing.connection.Pipe')` and `help('multiprocessing.Pipe')` yields no significant documentation regarding a 'closed' property.  I can orchestrate my code to pass c (into another process) and check `c.closed`, but I'm a tad surprised that there isn't a more documented, elegant way.